# Different version of outer dependency in my nuget

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I'm building my library and want to pack it into nuget package. Inside my library there is dependency on (in example)  Polly version 7.2.0.

And I want to achieve this behavior if user of my nuget add it to project he is able to upgrade Polly to version 7.+. In other words he can use all version between version used in my library (7.2.0) and next major version of Polly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Sorry, but exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to allow users of your library to upgrade the library's dependency?